# InkCanvas Strokes are not rendered with proper bounds when switching PC

Tags: uwp, inkcanvas

I have one UWP App using a UWP InkCanvas with a Load and Save Ink Buttons. I made a draw with the app on one laptop, saved the ink as a gif (+embedded isf) and sent the gif file to another laptop with a smaller screen to try it out.

When opening the ink with the same app but on this other laptop, the draw is clipped at the boundaries, as if it does not fit the screen, which arguably is due to the laptop's smaller screen size.

I tried to resize the InkCanvas as a whole by encapsulating it in a Scrollviewer but the draw follows the InkCanvas zooming, hence the draw remains clipped at the boundaries. Same with a render transform on the InkCanvas. I also tried the copy paste methods of the StrokeContainer when loading the ink. It does not work and furthermore I find it bulky as one needs to loop through all strokes to get them selected and then copy pasted.

I am looking at a way to automatically resize the InkCanvas (preferred) or the Strokes such that the drawing appears entirely on the InkCanvas, regardless of the size of the laptop's screen. I was expecting this to happen by default but somewhat it does not.

Although the code I use is very simple, I provide it as a start:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Background="White" Grid.Row="1">
         <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas"/>
    </Grid> 
    <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Load" Click="LoadButton_Click"/>
            <Button Content="Save" Click="SaveButton_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>


    private async void LoadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".isf");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".gif");

        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        if (file != null)
        {
            IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

            using (var inputStream = stream.GetInputStreamAt(0))
            {
                await inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.LoadAsync(inputStream);
            }
            stream.Dispose();

     }
    }
```

Comment: Can you also include the `SaveButton_Click` event handler?

Answer (score 3):

The `StrokeContainer.SaveAsync()` method will create a GIF. I am not sure exactly how it preserves the ink stroke data, but it seems to be point for point. Since your `InkCanvas` is stretching based on its parent `Grid`, its final bounds will be different screen to screen, and even in resized UWP window.

So, when you reload the stroke data, it will put the points exactly where it was generated. It will not transform anything for you. This is raw data.

If you want the data to appear in a different location, you can apply a transformation on the points. Here's a quick sample of how to shrink all data by 50%:

```
var container = inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer;
var strokes = container.GetStrokes();
var bounds = container.BoundingRect;
var center = new Vector2((float)bounds.Left, (float)bounds.Top);
var transform = Matrix3x2.CreateScale(.5f, .5f, center);

foreach (var stroke in strokes)
{
    stroke.PointTransform *= transform;
}
```

You could put that snippet of code after `await container.LoadAsync(inputStream)`.

You need to decide what to do with your output. It will depend on the user experience you want. If you want to scale the output, use the snippet above. If you want to move it, then use `Matrix3x2.CreateTranslation(...)`.

Comment: Laith, I tried something similar and it works, but LoaadAsync already loads all strokes and displays. Implementing a transform requires me to hide the canvas to improve the UX or the user will see a flash during the re-display. One should also scale the strokes's sizes by the same factor. This brings me to the question: How to read the raw data without displaying them (hence overriding LoadAsync or creating a new Load method), transform the data and display. It will be cleaner. But I have no clue on how to load the data in my own and be able to read the strokes objects. Cheers

Comment: `inkCanvas.Opacity = 0` ... load data ... `inkCanvas.Opacity = 1` ... does that work?

Comment: I did not try opacity, but I assume it would work. I made it work by switching off Visibility....